# CreateJS and two similar progress Event type

Tags: events, progress, createjs

`createjs.SpriteSheetBuilder` use simple **Event** with "progress" type, but, createJS already have **ProgressEvent** with similar type "progress". Because of this, we have two different event classes with the same logic.

Is this a bug?

https://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/SpriteSheetBuilder.html
https://www.createjs.com/docs/preloadjs/classes/ProgressEvent.html

Answer (score 0):

The SpriteSheetBuilder potentially could have used ProgressEvent, however, it is not part of the EaselJS library (just PreloadJS), and each library is intended to function independently.

While it has a similar purpose, the progress from SpriteSheetBuilder doesn't need to have the granularity that PreloadJS does, so a simple event with the type "progress" suffices. Making the class shared between the libraries would have added a (small) filesize bloat for almost no value.

Hope that helps!